# match route using a splat. What does it do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I see this route:

`match "*a", to: 'application#some_error_handler', via: :all`

What does that do in Rails? Is that a splat "a"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called *route globbing* and is explained in the [Routing guide's section on *route globbing*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments):

> Route globbing is a way to specify that a particular parameter should be matched to all the remaining parts of a route. For example:
>
> ```
> get 'photos/*other', to: 'photos#unknown'
> ```
>
> This route would match `photos/12` or `/photos/long/path/to/12`, setting `params[:other]` to "12" or "long/path/to/12". The fragments prefixed with a star are called "wildcard segments".
>
> Wildcard segments can occur anywhere in a route. For example:
>
> ```
> get 'books/*section/:title', to: 'books#show'
> ```